# Baseball Statistic Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

**Problem**

If a batter has a batting average of 300 (he hits 30% of his times at bat), what is the probability that the batter has a streak of six hits?

**Attempt**

I see that there are 2^6 = 64 possible ways for him to bat (hit or miss, 6 times at bat).  But I'm not sure how to account for the 300 batting average.  If he were at bat only once, I see that he would have a 30% chance of hitting the ball.  If he were at bat twice, I think he would have a 30% chance of hitting the 2nd time.  And, 0.3 * 0.3 = 0.09 = 9% chance of hitting two in a row.  So, (by induction?) can I assume that the chance that he hits 6 in row would be (0.3)^6 = 0.000729 = 0.0729%?

Comment: Your assumption is right.

Comment: This problem came from a section of my textbook that specifically covered (n+r-1,r).  How is (n+r-1,r) related to this problem????

Comment: I don't know the relation between (n+r-1,r) and this problem. But suppose there are 3 red balls and 7 blue balls. Each time, the pitcher pick one of the ten balls randomly to throw. The batter will hit red ball but loss the blue ball. When he hit 6 times. There are 10^6 different sequences of balls the batter can throw. And 3^6 of them lead to a streak of six hits.

Comment: Do you intend to take into account that he may have $400$ at bats (or some other number) in a season?

Comment: @YangzheLau Thanks very much for that alternate way of viewing the problem.  It helps very much.

Comment: @Henry  I didn't think to take that into account, although, I'm not sure.  Wouldn't the question be worded to include a certain number of at bats to find that percentage?